# Insert Items in Sharepoint List one by one separated by comma

Tags: asp.net

[image: Click here to see the image]

In the above image there is a asp page for UserPicker control and DropDown for Permission Level , While adding Add User Button it is added in the Employee List as shown in red boundary : dashboard.

While adding another permission level for same user for Finance , Finance Should be updated after dashboard separated comma as dashboard, Finance rather it created another Item.

Please help me bind the list items one by one separated by Comma.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to change single select dropdown to mutli select? This way you would easily be able to achieve what you need (OOB Multichoice field in SharePoint is rendered as a comma seperated string - just what you need). Otherwise you would have to write some custom code (CSOM) which would update item on Save button click. It should not be really problematic, but using multi select dropdown control for sure would be the easiest option.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I have Acheived Using foreach and concantenated with the previous Item